# Access-Control-Expose-Headers setting ignored

Tags: jquery, ajax, apache, http-headers

In my Apache web server configuration, I add support for two headers that are not part of the standard six:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Content-Disposition,X-Filename
```

My file export CGI script prints headers containing data for these two fields, e.g.:

```
...
print "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=%s\n" % (out_fn)
print "X-Filename: %s\n" % (out_fn)
...
```

My client-side AJAX call tries to retrieve the value of `Content-Disposition` on a successful AJAX request:

```
var export_form = new FormData();
export_form.append("settings", JSON.stringify(settings));
export_form.append("format", format);
$.ajax({
    url: "services/export_data.py",
    type: "POST",
    async: true,
    cache: false,
    data: export_form,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function(response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log("success");
        console.log(jqXHR.getAllResponseHeaders());
        console.log(jqXHR.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition'));
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("export_form submit failed:", jqXHR.status, jqXHR.statusText);
        console.log(jqXHR);
    }
});
```

My test requests on the client side complete and run the `success` callback, and I get the file data back in the `response` field, but I get `null` for the response header `Content-Disposition`.

In other words, a sample result of `console.log(jqXHR.getAllResponseHeaders())` is:

```
Date: Sat, 04 Mar 2017 19:42:27 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_python/3.5.0- Python/2.7.5 mod_perl/2.0.10 Perl/v5.16.3
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/pdf
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Content-Disposition,X-Filename
Connection: Keep-Alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
```

While the result of `console.log(jqXHR.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition'))` is empty:

```
null
```

Why is my AJAX request not able to retrieve the value of `Content-Disposition`, when I have made it explicitly available via the web server configuration, and I have set it correctly in the response?

---

To address issues with newlines, I used `sys.stdout.write` to get more control over the output, e.g.:

```
sys.stdout.write("Content-Type: %s\n" % (mime_type))
sys.stdout.write("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=%s\n" % (output_fn))
sys.stdout.write("X-Filename: %s\n" % (output_fn))
sys.stdout.write("Content-Description: File to download\n\n")
with open(out_fn, "rb") as out_fh:
    sys.stdout.write(out_fh.read())
```

Unfortunately, these two headers were still not visible to the AJAX response via `console.log(jqXHR.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition'))` and `console.log(jqXHR.getResponseHeader('X-Filename'))`, which were both `null`.

Comment: Are the headers actually included in the response (can you see them in the browser's developer console)?

Comment: @AlexReynolds when you use python `print`, you don't have to add a new line escape character because the `print` actually adds that. Are you sure `mod_headers` Apache module is enabled? It works flawlessly on me without new line characer string termination when I do the AJAX call from another domain and it returns the headers. Please have a look at the screenshot here: http://zikro.gr/dbg/srv/apache-custom-cors-headers-1.png. I can't give you a link, because I run the Apache server on a virtual machine, but I can make it available if you want to see it.

Comment: I have opened my VM running Apache 2.4 with a working example. You can try the working script with your AJAX call here http://zikro.gr/dbg/srv/apache-headers/, and if you check the source you will see the url is on a different server. Both `print` and `sys.stdout.write` are working and output the headers at the console window. See the console screenshot here http://zikro.gr/dbg/srv/apache-custom-cors-headers-2.png. Did you check the log files for potential errors? Does the AJAX call return `200 Success`?

Comment: You're writing `Unfortunately, these two headers were still not visible to the AJAX response`. Are they actually in the response and simply not visible to the Javascript code or are they not included in the response at all? Could you post the raw response with the headers and maybe the first few bytes of the data included? You could do it with your browser's developer console or tools like curl.

Comment: @Bewusstsein if the headers are included in the response, then the javascript AJAX XHR object will have access to these headers and output them to the console window. You can open the working example I provide at my comment above and check the console window for the results.

Comment: @AlexReynolds can you please provide the whole python cgi script? Remember that HTTP response won't capture your headers if you write anything else before the headers. If there is no output before the script writing the headers, then the example using the `sys.stdout.write` should work. (Also I assume you are importing `sys` library before you use `sys.stdout` using `import sys`).

Answer (score 0):

`Access-Control-Expose-Headers` only applies to CORS requests: `Content-Disposition` and `X-Filename` in your case are added to the six standard headers that another domain is allowed to see if it requests data from your server.

The request you're sending doesn't look like it's cross-origin, though: the URL `services/export_data.py` doesn't point to another domain and the output of `console.log(jqXHR.getAllResponseHeaders())` includes headers like `Server` or `Date` that aren't in the six standard and two exposed headers.

---

I think your problem is server-side, not with the Javascript, and that you're not actually sending the two headers you want to include.

The CGI script seems to be written in Python (based on the file extension in the URL). If that's the case `print "\n"` actually prints two newlines and, since an empty line delimits headers and data in HTTP, the two headers you're adding would be included in the HTTP response but are treated as data and not headers. Is there any `print` statement before you're adding the `Content-Disposition`? That would explain why that's also not showing up as a header.

To solve this simply remove the trailing `\n` in your script:

```
...
print "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=%s" % (out_fn)
print "X-Filename: %s" % (out_fn)
...
```